# Installing Ubuntu from Windows 7 Problem

Tags: 14.10

I have Acer Aspire One D271 netbook. It has Inte(R) Atom(TM) N2600 1.6GHz and 2GB DRR3 RAM. It runs Windows 7 and I've tried to change it to Ubuntu but when I boot my device with the flash drive inserted, it will not continue just black with a blinking cursor.

What's wrong with it? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you are trying to boot to a live cd/dvd/pendrive, or that you are trying to install/installed Ubuntu and are trying to boot to it?

Comment: I am trying to boot live pendrive.